# Optical Theorem ,how can experiment distinguish the unscattered wave from the forward scattered wave?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

How can experiment distinguish the unscattered wave from the forward scattered wave?

The Optical Theorem says the imaginary part of the forward wave determines the cross section
for an initial two-particle state $|i\rangle$ in the center of mass frame through the equation
$$2E_Tp_{in}\sigma=Im{\cal M}_{ii}$$

Comment: Why are you interested in distinguishing between the two? The optical theorem doesn't relate the total cross section to the forward scattering cross section, but to the forward amplitude, and only to the imaginary part of it.

Comment: You might find this post relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/55165/103628